# Custom cells reload issue while scrolling UITableView

Tags: uitableview, scroll

I have a UITableView where in i am using a custom UITableViewCell. All is well until the UITableView is scrolled. As soon as i scroll the UITableView the cells in Second section starts showing the content of cell in the first section.

I am using Storyboard for my project.

Here is the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

LS_Custom_Cell *customCell = (LS_Custom_Cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LS_Custom_Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
    customCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [customCell.btnAddContact addTarget:self
                                 action:@selector(btnAddContactAction:)
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    customCell.btnSelectContact.hidden   = YES;
    customCell.btnAddContact.hidden      = NO;
    customCell.lblAddContactText.hidden  = NO;
    customCell.lblContactName.hidden     = YES;
    customCell.lblContactEmailId.hidden  = YES;
}else if (indexPath.section == 1){
    customCell.lblContactName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]];
    customCell.lblContactEmailId.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"email"]];
}

return customCell;
}
```

I am also attaching images in order to clarify the issue further.

This screenshot is the first time when table loads records seems perfect

http://postimg.org/image/y2114vjdl/

As soon as i start scrolling cell from the first section appears in second section

http://postimg.org/image/c5ei4i66x/

This is first time i am posting a question here so please forgive me if there are any mistakes. Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LS_Custom_Cell *customCell = (LS_Custom_Cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LS_Custom_Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        customCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [customCell.btnAddContact addTarget:self
                                     action:@selector(btnAddContactAction:)
                           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        customCell.btnSelectContact.hidden   = YES;
        customCell.btnAddContact.hidden      = NO;
        customCell.lblAddContactText.hidden  = NO;
        customCell.lblContactName.hidden     = YES;
        customCell.lblContactEmailId.hidden  = YES;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        customCell.btnSelectContact.hidden   = NO;
        customCell.btnAddContact.hidden      = YES;
        customCell.lblAddContactText.hidden  = YES;
        customCell.lblContactName.hidden     = NO;
        customCell.lblContactEmailId.hidden  = NO;
        customCell.lblContactName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]];
        customCell.lblContactEmailId.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"email"]];
    }

    return customCell;
}
```